# How can I set default variables for every session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, node.js-connect

I have set up my express/connect app to use sessions with redis as the store:

```
app.use(express.session({
        secret: "secret key here",
        store: app.redisStore,
        cookie: { maxAge: 600000 }
    }));
```

I have created my own flash message system by doing the following:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    'use strict';

    //set-up session messages
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        /* set up flash*/
        if (req.session.flash === "undefined") {
            req.session.flash = [];
        }

        res.locals.messages = function () {
            var messages = req.session.flash;
            //clear out messages
            req.session.flash = [];
            return messages;
        };
        ...
```

Then essentially I just push flash message objects into the flash array whenever I need them. Every time the message function is used they get cleared out. This seems to work for the most part; however, while logging out I use the regenerate function and flash becomes undefined:

```
function logout(req, res) {
            var currentUser = req.session.currentUser;
            req.session.regenerate(function (err) {
                req.session.flash.push({"type": "info", "message": "You have been logged out."});
                console.log(currentUser + " Logged Out");
                res.redirect("/login");
                return;
            });
        }
```

Which seems to make sense. Regenerate obliterates the session, and since it happens after the initial request flash becomes undefined. To avoid any future problems like this I am wondering if there is there some sort of initialize function for sessions that I can override or hook into? I'd use this to set some default session values every time a session is started or regenerated.

Side-question: Is flash actually getting saved in redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To avoid any future problems like this I am wondering if there is
>   there some sort of initialize function for sessions that I can
>   override or hook into? I'd use this to set some default session values
>   every time a session is started or regenerated.

No, the way you are doing this is correct. If you want to attach multiple actions to `regenerate` method, then you can also try something like this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var session_events = new EventEmitter( );

module.exports = function (app) {
    'use strict';

    //set-up session messages
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        var regenerate = req.session.regenerate;
        req.session.regenerate = function() {
            session_events.emit( "session_regenerated", req );
            regenerate.apply( req.session, arguments );
        };

        /* set up flash*/
        if (req.session.flash === "undefined") {
            session_events.emit( "session_initializing", req );
        }
        // other code goes here
    });
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
session_events.on( "session_regenerated", function(req) {
    req.session.flash.push({"type": "info", "message": "You have been logged out."});
});
session_events.on( "session_initializing", function(req) {
    req.session.flash = [];
});
```

This is a monkey patch, though ( at least the `.regenerate` overriding ), so I advice writing your own [session store](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-session.html), which is not difficult at all, since session is nothing else then an entry in Redis/any other storage.

> Side-question: Is flash actually getting saved in redis?

Yes, everything attached to `session` goes to session store ( Redis in your case ).